# Adding a link in a side bar with php code

Tags: php, hyperlink

Sorry, guys, I'm a newbie to PHP.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCL6N.png)I have a social media site based purely on PHP, I would like to add a link to the right sidebar, but I am not very good at PHP.

This part is the sidebar.phtml

```
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo Wo_SeoLink('index.php?link1=explore');?>" data-ajax="?link1=explore">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#8BC34A" d="M14.19,14.19L6,18L9.81,9.81L18,6M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M12,10.9A1.1,1.1 0 0,0 10.9,12A1.1,1.1 0 0,0 12,13.1A1.1,1.1 0 0,0 13.1,12A1.1,1.1 0 0,0 12,10.9Z"></svg><img src="<?php echo $wo['config']['theme_url'];?>/img/sidebar/explorein.svg"> <?php echo $wo['lang']['explore'];?>
                </a>
            </li>
```

I want to add a link going outside the site.

Comment: What is the issue your facing?

Comment: What do you mean by an "outside link" that you want to add (per the image)?